# Dependency Injection in EF-core OnModelCreating method

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core, ef-core-2.2

I want to invoke some of my own services in the `OnModelCreating` method of the `DbContext`. What do I need to do?

I can inject the service via the `DbContext` constructor. But it doesn't seem effective enough as the method is called once on the application startup and I have to fatten my entire DbContext class for it.

```
public PortalContext(DbContextOptions<PortalContext> options, IPasswordService passwordService) : base(options)
{
    this._passwordService = passwordService;
}

...

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    ...
    entity<User>().HasData(
     new User
     {
       UserName = "admin",
       Password = this._passwordService.EncryptPassword("passw0rd");
     }
    );
    ...
}
```

Can the above code be replaced with the one:

```
public PortalContext(DbContextOptions<PortalContext> options) : base(options)
{
}

...

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    ...
    var passwordService = GetPasswordService(); // How?
    entity<User>().HasData(
     new User
     {
       UserName = "admin",
       Password = passwordService.EncryptPassword("passw0rd");
     }
    );
    ...
}
```

Comment: (Not sure) Try this.Database.GetService<T>()

Comment: There is no such method.

Comment: It's an extension method and sits in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure namespace.

Comment: Yes. It works. Thanks @artur.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use

```
this.Database.GetService<IPasswordService>();
```

It's an extension method and sits in `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure` namespace

Comment: @Khodaie, did you already try to create migration with this code snippet? I think it will throw exception because your service provider doesn't have `IPasswordService` registered when ef-tool creates instance of `PortalContext`.

Comment: You should register this service in your `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory` class.